# React Native Failed to ImportScripts Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting an ImportScripts error which means I'm not importing or exporting something correctly I'm guessing. I've narrowed it down to the `import { getPath } from '~/redux/modules/camera'` line. But I'm not sure why I get an error. I import connect so I have access to `dispatch` and then I import the `getPath` function. What else should I be doing? Thanks!

[image]

```js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getPath } from '~/redux/modules/camera'


class NimbusCamera extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }
  state = {
    camera: {
      aspect: Camera.constants.Aspect.fill,
      captureTarget: Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.disk,
      type: Camera.constants.Type.front,
      orientation: Camera.constants.Orientation.auto,
      flashMode: Camera.constants.FlashMode.auto,
    }
    isRecording: false,
    timeLeft: 30,
    limitReached: false
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Camera
          ref={(cam) => {
            this.camera = cam;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          aspect={this.state.camera.aspect}
          type={this.state.camera.type}
          captureTarget={this.state.camera.captureTarget}
          captureAudio={true}
          flashMode={this.state.camera.flashMode}
          >
          <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.startRecording.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
          <Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.stopRecording.bind(this)}>[STOP_RECORDING]</Text>
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }
  startRecording = () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      this.camera.capture({mode: Camera.constants.CaptureMode.video})
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      this.setState({
        isRecording: true
      });
      let timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
      function countdown() {
        if (this.state.timeLeft === 0) {
          clearTimeout(timerId);
          this.setState({isRecording: false})
        } else {
          this.setState({timeLeft: this.state.timeLeft--})
        }
      }
    }
  }

  stopRecording = () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      this.camera.stopCapture();
      this.setState({
        isRecording: false
      });
    }
  } 
}

export default connect()(NimbusCamera)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color: '#000',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 40
  }
});
```

Here is my redux camera module.

```
const GET_PATH = 'GET_PATH'
const CLEAR_PATH = 'CLEAR_PATH'

initialState = {
    videoPath: ''
}

export function getPath (path) {
    return {
        type: GET_PATH,
        path
    }
}

export function clearPath () {
    return {
        type: CLEAR_PATH
    }
}

export default function camera (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_PATH : 
            return {
                ...state,
                videoPath: action.path
            }
        case CLEAR_PATH : 
            return {
                ...state,
                videoPath: ''
            }
        default : 
            return state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any log in your packager console? usually it print much more detail error info.

Comment: In  my case, sometimes I stop debug from remote, and then, another error info which is more useful print on the red screen.

Comment: Thanks! I've narrowed it down to the `import { getPath } from ~/redux/modules/camera` that is causing the issue but not sure why. I'm exporting it correctly I believe. I've updated the question.

Comment: change ~/redux/modules/camera to absolute path and have a try

Answer (score -2):

errors like these pops-up also when you make a typo in your code. Then module cannot be properly imported. Check your code for typos first :)

Comment: Hey. I've narrowed it down to one import that is causing the error but still not sure why. I've updated the question.

Comment: @maxwellgover maybe try changing '~/redux/modules/camera' to path using relative notation eg. './redux/modules/camera' or '../redux/modules/camera' depending of location of your camera.js

Comment: I reset the cache and it works now. Feel like I'm doing that every 10 minutes ha.